# how to import a product programatically in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I tried importing a single product in magento 2..It failed..

I tried a script in magento 2 root directory and 
My code is

```
 <?php 
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[Bootstrap::PARAM_REQUIRE_MAINTENANCE] = true; // default false
$params[Bootstrap::PARAM_REQUIRE_IS_INSTALLED] = false; // default true
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

    $simple_product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $simple_product->setSku('Tops');
    $simple_product->setName('tops');
    $simple_product->setAttributeSetCode('Default');
    $simple_product->setCategories('Default Category/Women');
    $simple_product->setStatus(1);
    $simple_product->setTypeId('simple');
    $simple_product->setPrice(10);
    $simple_product->setProductWebsites('base');
    $simple_product->setCategoryIds(array(31));
    $simple_product->setUrlKey ('tops');
$simple_product->setColor('Red');
    $simple_product->setStockData(array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
        'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
        'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
        'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
        'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
        'qty' => 100 //qty
        )
    );

    $simple_product->save();

    $simple_product_id = $simple_product->getId();
    echo "simple product id: ".$simple_product_id."\n";
?>
```

and i am getting the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) ON DELET) in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(95): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) #3 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/ in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 235
```

Can anyone give me a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Simple Product Working on M2

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include("../app/bootstrap.php");
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$simpleProduct = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$simpleProduct->setSku('Testing3');
$simpleProduct->setName('Testing3');
$simpleProduct->setAttributeSetId(9);
$simpleProduct->setCategoryIds(3);
$simpleProduct->setDescription('This is for testing');
$simpleProduct->setStatus(1);
$simpleProduct->setTypeId('simple');
$simpleProduct->setPrice(500);
$simpleProduct->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
$simpleProduct->setVisibility(4);
$simpleProduct->setUrlKey('Testing3');

$simpleProduct->setStockData(array(
    'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
    'qty' => 100//qty
        )
);

$attr = $simpleProduct->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
$attributeOptionId = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId('Red'); //name in Default Store View
$simpleProduct->setData('color', $attributeOptionId);

$simpleProduct->save();
$simpleProductId = $simpleProduct->getId();
echo "Simple Product ID: " . $simpleProductId . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the updated version of your code. Please use this code to create product.

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include("app/bootstrap.php");
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$simple_product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$simple_product->setSku('tops123');
$simple_product->setName('tops');
$simple_product->setAttributeSetId(4);;
$simple_product->setCategories('Default Category/Women');
$simple_product->setStatus(1);
$simple_product->setTypeId('simple');
$simple_product->setPrice(10);
$simple_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
$simple_product->setCategoryIds(array(31));
$simple_product->setUrlKey ('tops343225');
$simple_product->setColor('Red');
$simple_product->setStockData(array(
    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
    'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
    'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
    'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
    'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
    'qty' => 100 //qty
    )
);


$simple_product->save();
$simple_product_id = $simple_product->getId();
echo "simple product id: ".$simple_product_id."\n";
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the code...Its works.!! The product is imported into catalog_product_entity table but still it shows duplicate entry constraint violation error while running the script...Is there any solution?

Comment: In this code you have to change the value of sku, because sku is unique for every product in magento.
Thanks

Comment: And if I need to update this product? When I update this programatically creates a duplicated product adding some digits to sku

Answer (score 0):

For configurable product working on M2

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include("../app/bootstrap.php");
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$productId = 809; // Configurable Product Id
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); // Load Configurable Product
$attributeModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute');
$position = 0;
$attributes = array(93, 135); // Super Attribute Ids Used To Create Configurable Product
$associatedProductIds = array(806, 807); //Product Ids Of Associated Products
foreach ($attributes as $attributeId) {
    $data = array('attribute_id' => $attributeId, 'product_id' => $productId, 'position' => $position);
    $position++;
    $attributeModel->setData($data)->save();
}
$product->setTypeId("configurable"); // Setting Product Type As Configurable
$product->setAffectConfigurableProductAttributes(4);
$objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable')->setUsedProductAttributeIds($attributes, $product);
$product->setNewVariationsAttributeSetId(9); // Setting Attribute Set Id
$product->setAssociatedProductIds($associatedProductIds); // Setting Associated Products
$product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
$product->save();
$configProductId = $product->getId();
        echo "Configurable product id: " . $configProductId . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include("./app/bootstrap.php");
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
 // add logging capability
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/import-new.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
            $simpleProduct = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
            $simpleProduct->setSku('Testing5');
            $simpleProduct->setName('Testing11115');
            // $attributeSetId = $simpleProduct->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
            $simpleProduct->setAttributeSetId(4);
            $simpleProduct->setCategoryIds(3);
            $simpleProduct->setDescription('This is for testing');
            $simpleProduct->setStatus(1);
            $simpleProduct->setTypeId('simple');
            $simpleProduct->setPrice(500);
            $simpleProduct->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
            $simpleProduct->setVisibility(4);
            $simpleProduct->setUrlKey('Testing445');
            $simpleProduct->setStoreId(1);
            $simpleProduct->setStockData(array(
                'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                'qty' => 100//qty
                    )
            );

            // $attr = $simpleProduct->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
            // $attributeOptionId = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId('Red'); //name in Default Store View
            // $simpleProduct->setData('color', $attributeOptionId);

            $simpleProduct->save();
            $simpleProductId = $simpleProduct->getId();
            echo "Simple Product ID: " . $simpleProductId . "\n";

?>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: use this code you can enter the simple product just enter the details according my script